# Can't resolve all parameters for MatProgressSpinner

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use Angular Material Progress spinner component. But if I import

```ts
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material';
```

I get the following error in the console:

> Can't resolve all parameters for MatProgressSpinner: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).

However if in the same way I import :

```ts
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material';
```

Progress bar works fine.

Dependencies:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    .....
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
   ....
  },
```

When I run `ng serve` I see this warning:

> WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/progress-spinner.es5.js 230:83-91 "export 'DOCUMENT' was not found in '@angular/common'
>   WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/progress-spinner.es5.js 283:83-91 "export 'DOCUMENT' was not found in '@angular/common'

How Can I correctly import `MatProgressBarModule`?

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the way you are trying to use `MatProgressSpinner`, not with the import itself. Can you provide code snippet of it? Do you use AoT build?

Comment: Problem arises when I only import module, but not use yet.

Comment: I see. I think the problem is that you have outdated angular version, that is not compatible with the version of angular/material you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your angular version is not compatible with the version of angular/material you are trying to use.

I found some issues on github that are suggesting angular version 4.2.6 or later. I checked it with current angular 4.4.5 and angular/material 2beta and its working ok.